# Who is it that suggests/starts a new Stack Exchange site in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

On [Area 51’s FAQ page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), it states “If your area of expertise doesn't already have a Stack Exchange site, propose it!”. I’m not entirely sure whether “expertise” means something similar to “professional” (someone who works in that field/subject) or whether it’s defined by each person.

For example, I have done few gigs within graphic design and had studied arts and computer science during undergraduate studies, but it is not my full-time job as of now. Would I be considered an “expert”? (This was just an easy example to get started; I do know there is a [graphic design Stack Exchange site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) already.)

I would like for a new community to be built: One towards neurodivergence. However, I am not a neurologist, psychiatrist, psychologist, nor therapist, but rather being a patient since preteens. Would I not count? Or does it also depend on what exactly the focus of that site would be towards?

I did check the [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) one, but it says

> [Psychology & Neuroscience] is a question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry

I was actually rather hoping there being one with the community, both asking and answering, would be those experiencing the neurodiverse aspect rather than those who’ve studied it, but have not personally experienced or questioned it. In some cases, they may end up like [Pinky](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/pinky-gloves-tampon-disposal-apology_uk_60780bc6e4b020e576c13a33) if they were over at Psychology & Neuroscience, where the people who have the "answer" are those who do not personally experience the things that are being questioned.

Similar to ones like [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), the people asking and answering questions are most likely not all directors, producers, screenwriters, actors, etc. for the films they question, such as Harry Potter.

(I know, no matter the person’s level of experience, they would need more than just themself for it to continue.)

Comment: Neologisms and euphemisms aside, neurodiversity would be covered by psychology and neuroscience.

Comment: Like any diversity, there's diversity in the definition: https://www.webmd.com/add-adhd/features/what-is-neurodiversity  https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/what-is-neurodiversity-202111232645#: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity

Answer (score 6):

Expertise can be an expert in the field or be self-defined, but you do need to be part of an existing group and to know that that existing group would like a site. If you're already part of a community with thousands of existing members then you can use Area 51 (Stack Exchange site) to give your community a place to ask and answer questions.

What has been found not to work however is a single individual creating a site and then hoping a community will form around it or even that an existing community that person is not a part of will find it and use it.

Note there is already a [Graphic Design site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) so we wouldn't want another of those.

There was also a previous [neurodiversity proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121277/neurodiversity), but it failed precisely for the reasons above, i.e., it didn't have a community willing to join/use it.

Our existing [Psychology site](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) does have some relevant tags though, such as [autism](/questions/tagged/autism) and [aspergers](/questions/tagged/aspergers), so some questions you might want to ask may fit there.

Comment: Yes, I made an edit. Where can I find more detail on that previous proposal? It still may be different as well.

Comment: Get 10,000 rep on area 51 and you can see its deleted proposals.

Comment: I just edited the question. I will go towards 10,000 as well. How can I do so?